# Commentary to Sefer Yetzirah of R. Yehuda Ben Barlizai

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, rishonim

Where can I find the commentary of R. Yehuda Ben Barzilai to the Sefer Yetzira? I am particularly looking for the 1858 Berlin ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21827) on HebrewBooks.